# Trying to get firebase image storage url in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I've successfully stored an image in firebase storage but whenever I want to retrieve the download url, it returns Object object. However the log shows valid string url.

P.S have a look at the code below. Thankyou

```
getImageUrl = async(fileName) => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    const ref = await firebase.storage().ref().child(`${currentUser.uid}/${fileName}.PNG`);
    ref.getDownloadURL()
     .then((url) => {
         console.log('url', url);   //this gives the valid img url
         return url;                //why is it returning the object?
     }).catch(error => {
       console.log('imageError', error);
       return null;
     });
}   


render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{(`${this.getImageUrl('2F1560068528')}`)}</Text>  //why is this showing an Object Object instead of download url?
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't async functions return Promise? So you would need to await in render and it should return Promise.resolve(url) or Promise.reject(null) depending ?

Comment: Just curious, but what logs out if you do this?
```console.log('url type is', typeof url)```

Comment: Also, could you try `return JSON.stringify(url)` to see if it stops saying Object object?

Comment: @kurokiiru I've already tried that it didn't work.

Comment: @SHG21 console.log('zzz', typeof url); it gives string and console.log('objectObject', typeof this.getImageUrl('1560068528')); gives object

Comment: hmm, try `...return url.json()).then(data => JSON.stringify(data))` then `<Text>{this.getImageUrl('2F1560068528')}</Text>`

Answer (score 0):

This is why you are getting back an Object.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html
Firebase.storage `returns` an Object.
It looks like when you are inside `ref.getDownloadURL()` function, `url` represents a string, but when it is `returned`, Firebase converts to an Object.